# Should badges be weighted on SO?

Tags: discussion, badges

My specialty is MSAccess.  Been working with it since last Century, in fact.  So I'm looking at some of the badges and I notice the Great Question badge requires a score of 100 or more:

[image]

OK, 4.7K awarded.  That ain't bad.  So, let me see how many of them were picked up by my fellow Access gurus.  I'll go hit the Access questions and sort by votes.

[image]

Not a single one of them has 100 votes??  Howie!  Can't be!  So, who's getting the votes?  It's all C++, git and Javascript, and many of them are in excess of 1,000 votes.  But I don't know those languages.

Now, I'm not saying I will ever ask a "great question", but I can say the probability I will get that badge asking an Access question is small.  Infinitesimal.  Nothing's impossible, but in 5+ years it hasn't been done.

So, in order to keep the badges fair, should the question tag be taken into account?

Comment: This would just encourage people to intentionally mis-tag questions.  For example they might add a bunch of popular tags, get a lot of votes, then remove all of the tags and add some obscure tag.  (Possibly reverting the tag changed after getting the badge.)

Comment: You think a question can get enough votes before someone fixes the tags?  Even if Access tags were worth X2, it would need 50 votes to earn a badge.  That's reasonable, and it isn't gonna hit 50 before someone catches the bad tagging.

Comment: 1) Ask question in popular tags which gets fast traffic and upvotes. 2) Change tags to obscure ones with much heavier badge weight (i.e. require less votes). 3) ??? 4) Profit.

Comment: You seem to not understand the situation.  If a C++ question requires 100 votes to get the badge, but a `visual-c++-2008-express` question only requires 30, then someone with a C++ question having 50 votes could remove the C++ tag and all other related tags, add this tag, get the badge, and then revert the change right away.

Comment: Cheaters never win, and winners never cheat.  If someone wants a badge that badly, it doesn't cost anything to give it to them.  But someone who does it legitimately at least has a shot at it.

Comment: It's not really worth bothering with it.  So some badges are impossible to get.  Ignore those, get on with your life.

Answer (score 4):

### Almost impossible ?

You cannot predict the response of user visiting your post.

81 Upvotes out of 96 000 views. Ok I get that they are not all logged in users but that still makes :

> 0.09% of votes.

It would have been very possible to get 100.

### Now.

We cannot favorite one tag over another. When you look at this, it looks like a not so bad idea but think about it a little ...

- All the badges...

35 000 + badges need to be assigned a "Is this likely to get a lot of votes" ? And same goes for all the tags added everyday...

- Easy to game the system

Oh the limit to get the gold badge in MsAccess is 50 votes instead of 100 ? *Quickly changing the tag to MsAccess when at 49 votes*.

- Users complaining...

Hey my C# Tag has 98 votes of weight and Java has 97 this is unfaire it's way harder to get votes in C# etc...

This is just on the top of my head.